# How to filter Map values using a Set of Strings?

Tags: java, dictionary, for-loop, lambda, set

I had to filter `Map` values using a `Set` of strings, I could make it work (a partner suggested to use `anyMatch()` in place of what I'm doing here, but I can't see how) and I wanted to know what do you think of this algorithm and if it is possible to improve it, maybe using another `Stream` function or even the `contains()` method, also I'm not sure if I can avoid iterating directly through the `Set` (for each loop).

```
ProductsResponse serviceResponse = (obtained from backend) ...;
Set<String> productIds = (some code to collect the strings from another API) ...;
//Here starts the filtering process 
serviceResponse.setProducts(serviceResponse.getProducts().entrySet().stream()
          .filter(product -> {
             for (String productId: productIds) {
                if (product.getKey().startsWith(productId)) {
                    return true;
                }
             }
             return false;
           }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

**Important note:** I'm using the `Set` to filter the products in the `Map`, the strings that are in the `Set` have almost the same format as the keys of the `Map`, so it is safe to compare them using the `startsWith()`

**Update 1:** adding the involved classes definition.

```
class ProductsResponse() {

  private Map<String, ProductResource> products;
}

class ProductResource () {

   private String productId;
   private String name;
   private Double price;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the surrounding code? What type is the value? It's difficult to help with such limited information.

Comment: Yes, sure, my bad there, I thought it was clear, I'll upload more code in a few minutes, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid inner for-loop by streaming through the set and using `anyMatch`:

```
serviceResponse.setProducts(serviceResponse.getProducts()
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(product -> productIds.stream().anyMatch(productId -> product.getKey().startsWith(productId)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

You can also use method reference for brevity:

```
serviceResponse.setProducts(serviceResponse.getProducts()
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(product -> productIds.stream().anyMatch(product.getKey()::startsWith))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Comment: Just a note - that's still an `O(m*n)` solution but at least it looks a bit better without the `for` loop.

Comment: Of course, the algorithm has not changed, thank you @VLAZ

Comment: Yes, just wanted to clarify. I've seen some people who assume that *iterating* through a Set is `O(1)` for some reason.

Comment: I don't believe that will compile.  When I did this I had to use `anyMatch(id->product.getKey().startsWith(id))`

Comment: @WJS yeah, I didn't test it and that was my thought too. I wrote it the way you did previously and then edited, but I'll probably revert, thank you!

Comment: @Andronicus I just tested using your first approach (with the method reference) and it compiled.

Comment: Yes!  I just redid it too (for a second time). Mea culpa. Must have done something wrong first time.  Good to know.

Answer (score 4):

If there are no two values `a` and `b` in the `productIds` set where `a.startsWith(b)`, then you can greatly improve performance by making the set a `TreeSet`.

```
TreeSet<String> productIds = (some code to collect the strings from another API) ...;
```

```
.filter(product -> {
   String id = productIds.floor(product.getKey());
   return (id != null && product.getKey().startsWith(id));
})
```

Or:

```
.filter(product -> Optional.ofNullable(productIds.floor(product.getKey()))
                   .map(product.getKey()::startsWith).orElse(false))
```

This changes performance from *O(n*m)* to *O(n*log(m))*, where `m` is the size of `productIds`.

---

**UPDATE**

If there *are* values `a` and `b` in the `productIds` set where `a.startsWith(b)`, then you need a little extra logic.

E.g. if the set contains `G` and `GED`, and you're checking if it contains prefix for `GET`, then `floor()` will return `GED`, so you have to strip off last character and repeat the lookup with `GE`, now returning `G`, to find that as a valid prefix.

So we need to add a loop to recheck:

```
.filter(product -> {
   String candidate = product.getKey();
   while ((candidate = productIds.floor(candidate)) != null) {
      if (product.getKey().startsWith(candidate))
         return true;
      candidate = candidate.substring(0, candidate.length() - 1);
   }
   return false;
})
```

It will slow the lookup a bit, but still be much better than a full sequential search.

Comment: I didn't know about the `floor()` operation existence, sounds good, I'll try it and do some testing to analyze the response times between your solution and the @Andronicus one, thanks guys.

Comment: @MarcoMarchetti The "find nearby" methods of [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) are entirely overlooked by most people. They just think of the Tree variants as sorted versions of the Hash variants. But, being sorted (`SortedSet`/`SortedMap`) and navigable (`NavigableSet`/`NavigableMap`) allows use of `first`, `lower` (<), `floor` (<=), `ceiling` (>=), `higher` (>), and `last` (named `xxxKey` and `xxxEntry` for the `Map`).

Comment: But that really only applies to the `natural ordering`.  If you sort a `set` of `Integers` in descending order, the methods behave just the opposite of what their names imply.  They can still be used, but it can be confusing.